# Dagger2 do not generate Dagger classes

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, kotlin-android-extensions

Dagger2 does not create classes Dagger*. I created the interface MyContainerComponent, but the class DaggerMyContainerComponent not created!

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc4"
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics:androiddevmetrics-plugin:0.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.0.6"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

in **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tegra.module.profile"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:1.0-rc4'

    //dagger
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

    //glide
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    //rxAndroid
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'

    //autoFactory
    compile group: 'com.google.auto.factory', name: 'auto-factory', version: '1.0-beta3'

    //retrofit
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'adapter-rxjava', version: '2.1.0'

    //OkHttp
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'

    //timber
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'

    //stetho
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.4.2'

    //constraint-layout
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

**MyContainerComponent.kt**

```
package com.tegra.module.profile.ioc

@Component(modules = arrayOf(ProfileModule::class))
@Singleton
public interface MyContainerComponent {
    fun inject(profileActivity: ProfileActivity)
}
```

**ProfileModule.kt**

```
package com.tegra.module.profile.bl.di

@Module
class ProfileModule(val application: Application) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication(): Application {
        return application
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContext(): Context {
        return application
    }
}
```

Any solutions? Already tried to: change gradle version, Clean, Rebuild, Change dependecy versions, also deleting the Gradle cache and reinstalling Android Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use Dagger annotations in *Kotlin* files you have to use `kapt` for Dagger compiler:

```
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
```

Also, delete all `apt` dependencies because `kapt` handles annotations in Java too.

[Official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#annotation-processing)

Comment: See documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#annotation-processing

Comment: Also do not apply `android-apt` if using `kotlin-android`